# Why are aliases missing inside of bash command?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

When I run in my terminal:

```
alias
```

a list with all my aliases (defined in `~/bashrc` and `~/.bash_aliases` files) will be displayed on my terminal. That's nice and as expected!

But when I run:

```
bash -c "alias"
```

there is no output, so no aliases. First I thought that `~/.bashrc` file is not sourced in the second case, so I ran:

```
bash -c ". ~/.bashrc && alias"
```

but, stupor, again there is no output...

Strangely enough, when I run:

```
bash -c ". ~/.bash_aliases && alias"
```

only the aliases defined in `~/.bash_aliases` will be displayed.

Can someone make some light and make me understand what exactly it is happening here?

Comment: `bash -c ". ~/.bashrc && alias"` shows the aliases for me. Are you sure it does not work?

Comment: @Bernhard Yep... Ubuntu 14.04, bash 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Exactly my configuration at the moment :)

Comment: @Bernhard I have in my `.bashrc` file the following code somewhere at the beginning `# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac` . You don't have it? ...So Cyrus answer exactly to my Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an interactive shell for alias definitions:

```
bash -i -c "alias"
```

Comment: Well spotted! You can add also to your answer the fact that `.bashrc` file will return immediately if not running interactively (see [this comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144932/why-are-aliases-missing-inside-of-bash-command#comment233649_144932)).